# Is SymPy correctly solving this ODE?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sympy, symbolic-math, differential-equations

I am using SymPy 1.4 from the Anaconda package to evaluate the tool. I have the following ODE to solve:

[image]

When using SymPy, I have the following code and result:

```
import sympy as sp
x=sp.Symbol('x')
y=sp.Function('y')(x)
diffeq=sp.Eq(sp.diff(y,x), (5*x**2-x*y+y**2)/x**2)
sp.dsolve(diffeq,y)
```

[image]

if I use WolframAlpha online I get:

[image]

Is this a bug in the software? If so, where can I report it?

Answer (score 2):

These are just different forms I think but represent the same set of solutions (although perhaps for different values of the integration constant). You can verify a solution to an ODE in SymPy using the `checkodesol` function:

```
In [9]: import sympy as sp 
   ...: x=sp.Symbol('x') 
   ...: y=sp.Function('y')(x) 
   ...: diffeq=sp.Eq(sp.diff(y,x), (5*x**2-x*y+y**2)/x**2) 
   ...: sol = sp.dsolve(diffeq,y)

In [10]: sol
Out[10]: 
                 5⋅x          
y(x) = ───────────────────────
            ⎛        ⎛ 2⎞⎞    
       2⋅tan⎝C₁ - log⎝x ⎠⎠ + 1

In [11]: checkodesol(diffeq, sol)
Out[11]: (True, 0)
```

You can also use a different method to solve the ODE and e.g. this method gives the same form as Wolfram:

```
In [12]: dsolve(diffeq, hint='separable_reduced')
Out[12]: y(x) = x⋅(2⋅tan(C₁ + 2⋅log(x)) + 1)
```

You can see the list of possible methods using `classify_ode`:

```
In [5]: classify_ode(diffeq)
Out[5]: 
('1st_homogeneous_coeff_best',
 '1st_homogeneous_coeff_subs_indep_div_dep',
 '1st_homogeneous_coeff_subs_dep_div_indep',
 'separable_reduced',
 'lie_group',
 '1st_homogeneous_coeff_subs_indep_div_dep_Integral',
 '1st_homogeneous_coeff_subs_dep_div_indep_Integral',
 'separable_reduced_Integral')
```

If you did want to report a bug in SymPy that you would open an issue on GitHub although I don't think that this is a bug:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Answer (score 0):

Long comment: This can also be considered as a Riccati DE, where one has the solution parametrization `y(x) = -x^2*u'(x)/u(x)`. Inserting this

```
u(x)*y'(x) = -x^2*u''(x) + x^2*u'(x)^2/u(x) - 2*x*u'(x)
             = (5*x^2*u(x) + x^3*u'(x) + x^4*u'(x)^2/u(x)) / x^2
```

then gives the second order linear DE

```
0 = x^2*u''(x) + 3*x*u'(x) + 5*u(x)
```

which is an Euler-Cauchy DE with characteristic polynomial `0=m*(m-1)+3*m+5=(m+1)^2+4`. This then gives the general solution as

```
 u(x) = A*x^(-1)*cos(2*log(x))+B*x^(-1)*sin(2*log(x))
```

Depending the way you reduce the parameter pair `(A,B)` to one parameter in the expression for

```
            (A-2*B)*cos(2*log(x)) + (2*A+B)*sin(2*log(x))
y(x) = x * -----------------------------------------------
                  A*cos(2*log(x)) + B*sin(2*log(x))
```

and how you then construct a phase shift parameter from it, you can get many expressions for the solution.